# Getting false value in subscribe Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6

I have the following function that checks if a code exists in the database:

```
isCodeExist(code: string): Observable < boolean > {
  return <Observable < boolean >> this.afs
    .collection(this.jobsCollection, ref => ref
      .where('code', '==', code)
      .limit(1)
    )
    .valueChanges()
    .pipe(
      flatMap(jobs => jobs),
      map(job => !!job)
    );
}
```

Here is how I'm using it:

```
onChangeCode() {
  this.jobService.isCodeExist(this.job.code)
    .pipe(
      tap(isCode => {
        console.log(isCode);
        // I want to show an error message based on true or false returned
        // this.showError = isCode;
      })
    )
    .subscribe();
}
```

I want to show an error message based on true or false returned but, console.log only logs true. if the value is false, the tap part never gets executed. Due to this, the error message appears when there is an existing code but never disappears.

**Update:**
I've tried `catchError()` inside the `pipe`, But i don't get any errors as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem by the following code:

```
isCodeExist(code: string): Observable < Job[] > {
  return <Observable < Job[] >> this.afs
    .collection(this.jobsCollection, ref => ref
      .where('code', '==', code)
      .limit(1)
    )
    .valueChanges();
}
```

```js
onChangeCode() {
  this.jobService.isCodeExist(this.job.code)
    .pipe(
      tap(code => {
        code.length > 0 ? this.codeAlreadyExists = true : this.codeAlreadyExists = false;
      })
    )
    .subscribe();
}
```

Ideally I wanted to return a Boolean value from the function itself but, that's not working out for me.